# Parent or Leaf in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please I have a table structured this way.

| Number | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I want to carry out a SQL Query that goes through the rows and for each row outputs one of two values for the case:

1. If the Number is a parent of another number, the case will output "Parent" Label for that row. e.g number 1 and 2
2. If the Number is not a parent i.e a leaf, the case statement will output "Not Parent" for that row. e.g Number 3.
   Please, how can I do this? I really am stumped about how to structure the case statement. New to SQL.
   Thanks

Comment: look for recursive cte, there are many many examples try some of them

Answer (score 2):

You can also use EXISTS

```
SELECT 
     Number, 
     case when exists (
           select 1 
           from mytable t2 
           where t2.Parent=t1.Number) 
     then 'Parent' else 'Leaf' end nmbrType
FROM mytable t1
ORDER BY Number
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Numbers that are `parent` are in the `parent` column.
2. Numbers that are `leaf` are not `parent`

```
select n.number,
       case 
          when p.parent is not null then ‘parent’
             else ‘leaf’
          end as number_type
  from mytable n
  left 
  join mytable p
    on n.number = p.parent;
```

Comment: Note a join can produce doubles, consider adding  (4,1) row to the table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH recursive cte AS (
  SELECT 
     Number, 
     Parent 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE mytable.Number=3
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 
     mytable.Number, 
     mytable.Parent 
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN mytable ON mytable.Number = cte.Parent
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

- Start by selecting the start values (`SELECT ... WHERE mytable.Number=3`)
- In the recusrive part select the parent (`SELECT FROM cte INNER JOIN ON ....`)

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/a5Vfr8wV)